# Increases Epoch will training using ResNet50

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I am using ResNet50 for training my model I have trained my model with 50 epochs and have saved model using .h5

```
r = model.fit_generator(
  training_set,
  validation_data=test_set,
  epochs=50,
  steps_per_epoch=len(training_set),
  validation_steps=len(test_set)
)
model.save('model_resnet50.h5')
```

So many question cam I load same model and train for 100 epochs if yes how can I do pleas help

Comment: Do you mean that you want to load the saved model and train it further? You can load it from the .h5 file and just train it.

Comment: can we taring using same code mins first I have 50 epochs them can I train same model for 100 by just changing epochs=50 to epochs=100 will it work

Comment: Have you tried it? If you did, was there any issue? Training for more epochs will just take more time to train. But do you actually need to train for more epochs? You should monitor training loss and validation loss during training to see whether more epochs can help to further improve the score of your model.